# How to add an AboutBox to a pyface TasksApplication?

Tags: enthought, pyface

For example, how to change the *examples/application/python_editor* code to add an `AboutAction` which needs its `application` attribute to be set? At the time it is required, *i.e.* in the definition of `PythonEditorTask` in *python_editor_task.py*, the application has not yet been created.

In general, what is the best approach to embed all my traitsui panels in a full-blown deployable application? Is *pyface* above or below *traitsui*?

I am also considering *envisage*... The same question: how to add an AboutBox to a Tasks plugin *envisage* application?